# SSRS 2008 R2 - How to change one report in ReportServer but change it to use different datasources

Tags: sql-server, ssrs-2008, reporting-services

I have one SSRS 2008 R2 report deployed to the ReportServer.

I want to be able to run the same report against different databases without having to either have multiple copies of the report or having to edit data sources.  I tried to use Linked Reports but that doesn't allow to change the data source of the report.

What is the best way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

We do this to do analysis on prior financial years. The answer lies in the fact that everything in Reporting Services is an expression, including the SQL statement.

We have a table of databases in a central location that populates a drop-down combobox of friendly names and database names, for example:

```
Current Accounts                 ACCOUNTS_LIVE
Financial Year End 2012          ACCOUNTS_FY2012
Financial Year End 2011          ACCOUNTS_FY2011
```

Then we link this up to a parameter called Database so the user can select which database they want (with the default value being the current database).

Then in your SQL statement you have something like:

```
="SELECT LedgerCode, Amount "
&"FROM " & Parameters!Database.Value & ".dbo.Ledgers "
```

This builds the SQL statement and points it to the database the user selects. No need to change data sources.

Comment: Ah Right, I should have explained that I am using MDX against cubes.

Comment: Nice solution for SQL connections though